# Hardware profiling instruments for running program under Linux?

Tags: profiling

Which tool is to use for CPU cycle, cache miss counting (for selected functions in user process)?

[TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) instruction doesn't count context switches, interruptions.

I made basic search on this field, see below. If this question isn't appropriated for SO please move it or vote for close...

In some blog post author uses [pfmon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/pfmon.1.html) command (for Itanium/ADM64/Intel P6 CPUs) to get CPU cycles count spending in selected functions.

This tool seems belong to http://perfmon2.sourceforge.net/ project.

There are [no corresponding packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637144/how-to-install-perfmon2-on-ubuntu) in Debian/Ubuntu.

Same is with http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/ project. I think this is for some good reason, but who know...

Also there is [Performance Counters for Linux](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) presented by `perf` tool and it available through `linux-perf` package.

Also I found vendor tools:

- [Intel VTune](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe) - free trial, 900$ licenced
- [AMD CodeAnalyst Performance Analyzer](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/archive/amd-codeanalyst-performance-analyzer/) - end of life, freeware
- [AMD CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/codexl/) - seems freeware

Comment: Sorry to ask the usual question: Is your purpose to find ways to speed up the program? In other words, are you looking for "bottlenecks", or are you just looking for numbers?

Comment: *bottlenecks*, to understand how code decisions make performance results

Comment: OK, then maybe you've seen [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/927773/23771), showing that there can be huge performance opportunities that have nothing to do with processor-level events.